# How to terminate a program using while loop

Tags: c, while-loop, terminate

I have made this calculator.

Everything works fine.

However, I want to use a while loop as follows:

```
char cont = 'y'
while (cont == 'y') {
    /code/
}
printf("Do you want to continue (y/n)")
scanf("%c", & cont)
```

This prints:

```
Do you want to continue (y/n)
```

But when I enter something the program ends unexpectedly.

Full Code:

```
#include < stdio.h > 
#include < conio.h >

void main() {
    float x, y, result;
    int select;
    char cont = 'y';
    clrscr();
    while (cont == 'y') {
        clrscr();
        printf(
            "Please Enter The Respective Number For Following Operation\n1. Addition\n2. Subtraction\n3. Multiplication\n4. Division\n"
        );
        scanf("%d", & select);
        clrscr();
        switch (select) {
        case 1:
            {
                printf("\nEnter The First Number To Add\n");
                scanf("%f", & x);
                printf("\nEnter The Second Number To Add\n");
                scanf("%f", & y);
                clrscr();
                result = x + y;
                printf("Addition of two numbers %f and %f is %f", x, y,
                    result);
                break;
            }
        case 2:
            {
                printf("\nEnter The First Number To Subtract\n");
                scanf("%f", & x);
                printf("\nEnter The Second Number To Subtract\n");
                scanf("%f", & y);
                clrscr();
                result = x - y;
                printf("Subtraction of two numbers %f and %f is %f", x, y,
                    result);
                break;
            }
        case 3:
            {
                printf("\nEnter The First Number To Multiply\n");
                scanf("%f", & x);
                printf("\nEnter The Second Number To Multiply\n");
                scanf("%f", & y);
                clrscr();
                result = x * y;
                printf("Multiplication of two numbers %f and %f is %f", x,
                    y, result);
                break;
            }
        case 4:
            {
                printf("\nEnter The Numerator\n");
                scanf("%f", & x);
                printf("\nEnter The Denominator\n");
                scanf("%f", & y);
                clrscr();
                result = x / y;
                printf("\nDivision of two numbers %f and %f is %f", x, y,
                    result);
                break;
            }
        default:
            {
                printf("Invalid Choice");
                break;
            }
        }
        printf("\n\nCalculator By XXX\n\nDo you want to Continue (y/n)\n");
        scanf("%c", & cont);
    }
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code to understand what is actually happening?

Comment: This code is unreadable.  Try to format it sanely before posting.

Comment: Indentation/formatting:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your while loop terminates because the `scanf("%c",&cont);` reads the leftover `\n` from the buffer which makes your `while` statement to fail.
 You should modify your scanf to `scanf(" %c",&cont);`.

Answer (score 0):

Put that `scanf` statement inside while loop or you can use `do..while` loop in place of `while`.

```
do { 
   // code
   printf("Do you want to continue (y/n)"); scanf("%c",&cont);

} while(cout=="y");
```